# Multiple CGI scripts in an HTML frameset

Tags: html, frameset

I have multiple (3-4) CGI scripts which should be presented on one HTML page.

I tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>TESTPAGE<BR></h1>

  <frameset cols="35%,20%,*">
    <frame src="./cgi-bin/1.cgi">
    <frame src="./cgi-bin/2.cgi">
    <frame src="./cgi-bin/3.cgi">
  </frameset>

</body>
</html>
```

Only TESTPAGE is shown, no cgi was opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. A [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) would have told you what the problem was.

You can't have a `<frameset>` inside a `<body>`. You use a `<frameset>` **instead** of a `<body>`.

When your browser encounters the `<frameset>`, it is already rendering a normal HTML body, so it ignores it because it has no place to put it.